# Is it necessary to de-normalize database for given scenario?

Tags: mysql, database-design, denormalization

I make a simple cms.

Each post has subject, content, and several image, and use 2 table

each time create new post, have to insert table a subject and content, then insert table b image, but if insert table b fail, have to delete last insert table a.
problem both happen when update and delete.

table a

```
article
id    subject    content
1
```

table b

```
article_image
id    article_id    file_path    file_sequence
1     1             dkeorkw.jpg  2
1     1             dklwekw.jpg  1
```

I'm wondering should i combine 2 table, any suggestion?
most people how to do

Comment: Your update is a whole new question about MVC methods - don't tack it onto the end of a question about database normalisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> most people how to do

You shouldn't combine the two tables as you'll have issues later on. Most people do normalized. See [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Most database systems come with mechanisms that allow you to transact both statements and rollback if one of them fails. You can read more about how MySQL handle's this in their [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-transactions.html):

> ```
> START TRANSACTION;
> INSERT ...;
> INSERT ...;
> COMMIT;
> ```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I use php without framework, I have this question because tried fit in mvc design pattern, I can't find the place do transaction, please read my update

Answer (score 1):

because of transaction management stuff you can not avoid the Structure. You should not combine the tables. If you will avoid this thing today, you will have junk of **de-normalized** data tomorrow. After that it will be very difficult to manage data. You will have one data at more places in your database. So I will not re command to do that. And most of frameworks provides transaction management itself. I don't know which framework and technology you are using but Spring (in Java) provides it very easily.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I use php without framework, I have this question because tried fit in mvc design pattern, please read my update

Answer (score 1):

You should perform your inserts in a transaction. That way if one of them fails, they all get cancelled.

For example

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO article (...) VALUES (...);
INSERT INTO image (...) VALUES (...);
INSERT INTO article_image (...) VALUES (...);
COMMIT;
```

If any of those insert fail for some reason, none of the insert will appear in the DB.